# Mapping sheet names via Dictionary

Tags: vba, excel

First post - Just started in VBA and the last programming I did was in Fortran...a number of years ago... I'll do my best to describe my problem as clearly as possible. If any more info is needed, please ask.

I am working to transform data that is provided for a number of facilities, each with its own sheet. The data needs to be transferred (amongst other things) to a new sheet in a format that makes it amenable to PivotTables, with the facility name in the first column. As the sheet names themselves are relatively unintelligible, I wanted to use the Dictionary to map the sheet names to more useful facility names.

My first step was to generate a list of the sheet names:

```
Sub SheetNames()
    Columns(1).Insert
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
        Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Once I had a list of the sheet names, I filled in the column next to them with the names I wanted them to map to.

I then populated the dictionary with

```
Set sites = New Dictionary

more = True
rw = 4 

While more
    sites.Add Worksheets("SiteMapping").Cells(rw, 1), Worksheets("SiteMapping").Cells(rw, 2)
    rw = rw + 1
   If Len(Worksheets("SiteMapping").Cells(rw, 1)) = 0 Then more = False
Wend

For Each v In sites.Keys
    Debug.Print "Sheet: " & v & " Site: "; sites.Item(v)
Next
```

Checking at the end to make sure that it did, in fact, work (it did).

So then, later in the subroutine, I wanted to use the sites dictionary to populate a range of x cells in the first column of a new sheet (name stored in variable "SheetName") using the following:

```
i = 1
For n = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 2
    v = Worksheets(n).Name
    Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(i, 1).Value = sites.Item(v)
    Debug.Print v & ", " & sites.Item(v)
    i = i + 1
Next n
```

(Last two sheets are ignored on purpose.)
The assignment does nothing, so I thought maybe I was just messing something up there (still totally possible!), so I added the debug statement, but all I get out is: "name of sheet, "
So then I was worried that somehow the values in the cells of my mapping sheet ("SiteMapping") were not actually matching those in the keys of the sites dictionary. So, I did a manual check:

```
k = Worksheets(2).Name
h = sites.Keys(42)
Debug.Print "Sites key is " & h
If Worksheets(2).Name = sites.Keys(42) Then
    Debug.Print "Yay!"
Else
    Debug.Print "Boo!"
End If
```

Response was positive ("Yay!"), but when I then tried:

```
Debug.Print sites.Item(h) & " is the value"
```

I still got " is the value" as my output.

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong here when it comes to calling values from the dictionary. Can anyone help me along? Thanks in advance!

edit 2014-03-21 - Thanks Simoco! That was exactly it! Still working through the whys as a newbie, but got it running again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
sites.Add Worksheets("SiteMapping").Cells(rw, 1), Worksheets("SiteMapping").Cells(rw, 2)
```

to

```
sites.Add Worksheets("SiteMapping").Cells(rw, 1).Value, Worksheets("SiteMapping").Cells(rw, 2).Value
```

Note, that I'm using `.Cells(rw, 1).Value` instead `.Cells(rw, 1)`, because in that case your dictionary items not strings, but Range objects.

Actually in your code you're using `Range` object for dictionary keys. That's why when you print values there it works:

```
For Each v In sites.Keys
    Debug.Print "Sheet: " & v & " Site: "; sites.Item(v)
Next
```

But not working here:

```
v = Worksheets(n).Name
Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(i, 1).Value = sites.Item(v)
```

because in first code `v` is `Range` object (and you get `Item` using key - `Range` object), but in second code `v` is `string`